# Change GarageBand key pitch/scale

Tags: garage-band

I am very new to GarageBand and music in general, so please excuse me if this is a noob question. I can display the virtual keyboard and play it. There is also an option to do pitch bend the keyboard, but if I press it, the pitch bend value can just be -20 or +20.

Say for example I am playing the C major chord on the keyboard, can I change the pitch/scale of the digital keyboard to changed to F major chord? I can change the key signature after I have recorded. But can I change while playing the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to change the pitch and scale real time. It's possible when you change the key signature it may effect any other MIDI instruments. Such as  your drum tracks if created on a MIDI keyboard, it may throw them off. Or possibly not.

If you are new to Garage Band, you could turn on the "Quick Help Button", that way you could hover your cursor over whatever is in GarageBand, and get contextual help right there.

If you are using Garage Band 10 or above, there is a 'Musical Typing' feature to assist you in real time changes.
Example: **Pitch Bend**- you could use the 1+2 keys to adjust the pitch of whatever notes you are playing in real time.
**Octave** Use the Z and X keys to shift octaves for lower or higher pitched notes. HTH. ~catz

Answer (score 0):

In the Inspector window (shortcut key: i) under MIDI defaults enter "5" in the transpose parameter.